# copy value from class in java

Tags: java

there is class (class0) that have value named foo.

I want to copy foo to bar.

I tried this:

```
bar = class1.foo;
```

But when I change bar, foo  will change...

what should I do?

**Note1:** the type of all values is `ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>>`.
Note2:i also tried

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>> getFoo(){
return new ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>>(foo);
}
```

Comment: The magic word is "reference" here. That's why it's a shame that modern languages don't force you to learn about pointers and references from ground up anymore.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Apparently it *does* force you to learn about references, otherwise the question wouldn't need to be asked.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes of course, but only when a problem arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>>(foo)
```

doesn't achieve the desired effect, I'll assume what you want is a deep copy.

The easiest way to do this would be to serialize it and then deserialize it, also - this would work with all serializable objects, regardless of complexity (collection of collection of collection of .... objects):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>> obj = null;
    try {
         FastByteArrayOutputStream fbos = 
                new FastByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fbos);
        out.writeObject(foo);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        ObjectInputStream in = 
            new ObjectInputStream(fbos.getInputStream());
        obj = (ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>>) in.readObject();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
```

You'd have to declare class2 as Serializable though.
If this is not an option, you'd have to declare a specific method that iterates over all arraylists in foo, copies them with

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<class2>>(foo.get(i));
```

and then puts them in the resulting ArrayList.

Comment: This is one hell of a workaround.  I would never use it but I kinda dig it.

Comment: Trust me, if you ever want to deep copy 

    ArrayList<HashMap<Hashtable<ArrayList<Set<Map<Object>>>>>

you'd use it.

Comment: +1. To do the same (deep clone) **in a single row**, you can use Apache Commons [`SerializationUtils.clone()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone%28java.io.Serializable%29)

Comment: Yeah, good but I also would not use it for the scenarios where it is not really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a copy constructor. You can find an example here: [copy constructor](http://www.javapracm/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12), the important part is:

```
public final class Galaxy {

  private double fMass;
  private final String fName;

  public Galaxy (double aMass, String aName) {
    fMass = aMass;
    fName = aName;
  }

  /**
  * Copy constructor.
  */
  public Galaxy(Galaxy aGalaxy) {
    this(aGalaxy.getMass(), aGalaxy.getName());
    //no defensive copies are created here, since 
    //there are no mutable object fields (String is immutable)
  }
}
```

Comment: The link that you gave in the comments of my answer against Cloneable (http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) was convincing. +1 for copy constructor and avoid Cloneable. I removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your object [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and override clone() method for a deep copy. You can get a good example [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/).

Another way is to use copy constructor. [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-java/) is an example.

Comment: what should i write? implement that just make new function!

Comment: override clone() method of Object class. For each variable of the class which you are cloning you must create new variables and not just copy references and then you can simply get a copy using **class0 cCopy = yourClass0Object.clone()** . Now you can access your data by **cCopy.getfoo()** or **cCopy.foo(if public)**.